# Who wrote the Shiva Stuti Sukta Malika, and does it still exist?

Tags: vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava, shaivism, agamas, shaiva-siddhanta

The Narayana Shabda Sadhararanyam is a work by the 16th century Advaita philosopher Govinda Nayaka which argues that the word Narayana refers to Brahma, Vishnu, and Shiva.  This work was refuted by an anonymous Sri Vaishnava in a work called the Narayana Shabda Niruktih.  [This excerpt](http://preview.ibb.co/f1NABa/image.jpg) from the Narayana Shabda Niruktih refutes certain Puranic citations given by Govinda Nayaka to try to show that Narayana also refers to Shiva.  The author argues that these Puranic verses are interpolations, because not even Shaivites have ever cited them before:

> You cited usages of interpretations explaining the term "narayana" as referring to Shiva.  However, these usages are not cited in the **Shaivite texts such as Nilakantha Bhashya, Shivarkamanidipika, Shivastutisuktamalika, Shivatattvaviveka, and Shaivakarnamrita, etc.**, which are extremely insistent upon establishing that the term "narayana" refers to Shiva.  Our texts, which refute the above texts line by line, also do not cite those passages.... [I]t is inevitable to suspect the existence of interpolations in the very Puranas, such as Shiva Purana, Skanda Purana, etc. The Shiva Purana, Skanda Purana, etc. are generally edited only by the Shaivites. Even narrations of greatness of modern temples are presented as though they belong in the Shiva Purana, Skanda Purana, etc. Therefore, the usages you cited are not at all from the puranas.

I'm interested in the part in bold.  Most of these Shaivite works are recognizable:

- The Nilakantha Bhashya, aka the Srikantha Bhashya, is Srikantha Sivacharya's Shaiva Siddhanta commentary on the Brahma Sutras.  You can read it in English [here](https://archive.org/details/TheVedantaSutrasWithSriKanthaBhashya).
- The Shivarka Mani Dipika is a subcommentary on the Nilakantha Bhasha composed by Appayya Dikshitar, a 16th century philosopher who was both an Advaitin and a member of the Shaiva Siddhanta sect.  As far as I can tell ir's never been translated into English, and I haven't found a Sanskrit version either, but it at least exists in manuscript form.
- The Shiva Tattva Viveka is Appayya Dikshitar's commentary on his own poem, the Sikharini Mala, and it seeks to show that Shiva is supreme.  You can read it in English [here](http://gdurl.com/UGXS/download).
- The Shiva Karnamrita is another work by Appayya Dikshitar.  I haven't found it in Sanskrit or English, but it at least exists in manuscript form.

But my question is, what is the "Shiva Stuti Sukta Malika" mentioned in the quote?  Who composed it, does it still exist, and has it been translated into English?

My initial thought was that it's yet another work by Appayya Dikshitar, but it's not included in the list of Appayya Dikshitar's works given in [this web page](http://shaivam.org/devotees/works-of-sri-appaiya-dikshita). In any case, I'm guessing that like the other four works, it's a work from th Shaiva Siddhanta sect.  If it helps, the name of the work means "garland of hymns in praise of Shiva".

Comment: Do you mean Sruti Sukti Mala by Sri Haradatta Sivacarya?
Please let me know the source of the translation of Shiva Tattva Viveka posted here.